# Elasticsearch not returning an exact match first

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elastic search index with a field for exact matches, and somehow i get both a lot of similar results (which I don't mind) and those similar results en up sorted before the exact match, (which i do mind.)

Can someone explain what's going on and how to fix it?

My mapping is like this

```
"exact":{
  "type":"string",
  "boost":10.0,
  "analyzer":"keyword"
},
```

My query that searches for "AAPL P JAN 2014 885,00" is like this:

```
{
  "size" : 21,
  "query" : {
    "field" : {
      "exact" : "AAPL P JAN 2014 885,00"
    }
  },
  "explain" : true,
  "sort" : [ {
    "_score" : {
      "order" : "desc"
    }
  } ],
  "facets" : {
    "category" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "category",
        "size" : 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the returned documents end up in this order:

- {"exact":["APPLE INC","US0378331005","AAPL","73773"],"id-compound":"AAPL"}
- {"exact":["AAPL","73773","AAPL P JAN 2014 675,00"],"id-compound":"AAPL*PUT*20140118*675"}
- {"exact":["AAPL","73773","AAPL C JAN 2014 500,00"],"id-compound":"AAPL*CALL*20140118*500"}

etc, with the exact match a bunch of results down the line.

Can someone explain to me why the exact match doesn't end on top?

The search results with full explain is below if it helps make sense of things.

```
"hits" : [ {
  "_shard" : 0,
  "_node" : "1",
  "_index" : "instruments",
  "_type" : "instrument",
  "_id" : "AAPL",
  "_score" : 1306.8339, "_source" : {"exact":["APPLE INC","US0378331005","AAPL","73773"],"id-compound":"AAPL"},
  "_explanation" : {
    "value" : 1306.8339,
    "description" : "product of:",
    "details" : [ {
      "value" : 6534.169,
      "description" : "sum of:",
      "details" : [ {
        "value" : 6534.169,
        "description" : "weight(exact:AAPL in 9096), product of:",
        "details" : [ {
          "value" : 0.25854474,
          "description" : "queryWeight(exact:AAPL), product of:",
          "details" : [ {
            "value" : 6.1701355,
            "description" : "idf(docFreq=211, maxDocs=37299)"
          }, {
            "value" : 0.0419026,
            "description" : "queryNorm"
          } ]
        }, {
          "value" : 25272.875,
          "description" : "fieldWeight(exact:AAPL in 9096), product of:",
          "details" : [ {
            "value" : 1.0,
            "description" : "tf(termFreq(exact:AAPL)=1)"
          }, {
            "value" : 6.1701355,
            "description" : "idf(docFreq=211, maxDocs=37299)"
          }, {
            "value" : 4096.0,
            "description" : "fieldNorm(field=exact, doc=9096)"
          } ]
        } ]
      } ]
    }, {
      "value" : 0.2,
      "description" : "coord(1/5)"
    } ]
  }
}, {
  "_shard" : 0,
  "_node" : "1",
  "_index" : "instruments",
  "_type" : "instrument",
  "_id" : "AAPL*PUT*20140118*675",
  "_score" : 163.35423, "_source" : {"exact":["AAPL","73773","AAPL P JAN 2014 675,00"],"id-compound":"AAPL*PUT*20140118*675"},
  "_explanation" : {
    "value" : 163.35423,
    "description" : "product of:",
    "details" : [ {
      "value" : 816.7711,
      "description" : "sum of:",
      "details" : [ {
        "value" : 816.7711,
        "description" : "weight(exact:AAPL in 18), product of:",
        "details" : [ {
          "value" : 0.25854474,
          "description" : "queryWeight(exact:AAPL), product of:",
          "details" : [ {
            "value" : 6.1701355,
            "description" : "idf(docFreq=211, maxDocs=37299)"
          }, {
            "value" : 0.0419026,
            "description" : "queryNorm"
          } ]
        }, {
          "value" : 3159.1094,
          "description" : "fieldWeight(exact:AAPL in 18), product of:",
          "details" : [ {
            "value" : 1.0,
            "description" : "tf(termFreq(exact:AAPL)=1)"
          }, {
            "value" : 6.1701355,
            "description" : "idf(docFreq=211, maxDocs=37299)"
          }, {
            "value" : 512.0,
            "description" : "fieldNorm(field=exact, doc=18)"
          } ]
        } ]
      } ]
    }, {
      "value" : 0.2,
      "description" : "coord(1/5)"
    } ]
  }
}, {
  "_shard" : 0,
  "_node" : "1",
  "_index" : "instruments",
  "_type" : "instrument",
  "_id" : "AAPL*CALL*20140118*500",
  "_score" : 163.35423, "_source" : {"exact":["AAPL","73773","AAPL C JAN 2014 500,00"],"id-compound":"AAPL*CALL*20140118*500"},
  "_explanation" : {
    "value" : 163.35423,
    "description" : "product of:",
    "details" : [ {
      "value" : 816.7711,
      "description" : "sum of:",
      "details" : [ {
        "value" : 816.7711,
        "description" : "weight(exact:AAPL in 383), product of:",
        "details" : [ {
          "value" : 0.25854474,
          "description" : "queryWeight(exact:AAPL), product of:",
          "details" : [ {
            "value" : 6.1701355,
            "description" : "idf(docFreq=211, maxDocs=37299)"
          }, {
            "value" : 0.0419026,
            "description" : "queryNorm"
          } ]
        }, {
          "value" : 3159.1094,
          "description" : "fieldWeight(exact:AAPL in 383), product of:",
          "details" : [ {
            "value" : 1.0,
            "description" : "tf(termFreq(exact:AAPL)=1)"
          }, {
            "value" : 6.1701355,
            "description" : "idf(docFreq=211, maxDocs=37299)"
          }, {
            "value" : 512.0,
            "description" : "fieldNorm(field=exact, doc=383)"
          } ]
        } ]
      } ]
    }, {
      "value" : 0.2,
      "description" : "coord(1/5)"
    } ]
  }
}, {
  "_id" : "AAPL*PUT*20140118*940",
  "_score" : 163.35423, "_source" : {"exact":["AAPL","73773","AAPL P JAN 2014 940,00"],"id-compound":"AAPL*PUT*20140118*940"},
  "_explanation" : {
    "value" : 163.35423,
    "description" : "product of:",
    "details" : [ {
      "value" : 816.7711,
      "description" : "sum of:",
      "details" : [ {
        "value" : 816.7711,
        "description" : "weight(exact:AAPL in 794), product of:",
        "details" : [ {
          "value" : 0.25854474,
          "description" : "queryWeight(exact:AAPL), product of:",
          "details" : [ {
            "value" : 6.1701355,
            "description" : "idf(docFreq=211, maxDocs=37299)"
          }, {
            "value" : 0.0419026,
            "description" : "queryNorm"
          } ]
        }, {
          "value" : 3159.1094,
          "description" : "fieldWeight(exact:AAPL in 794), product of:",
          "details" : [ {
            "value" : 1.0,
            "description" : "tf(termFreq(exact:AAPL)=1)"
          }, {
            "value" : 6.1701355,
            "description" : "idf(docFreq=211, maxDocs=37299)"
          }, {
            "value" : 512.0,
            "description" : "fieldNorm(field=exact, doc=794)"
          } ]
        } ]
      } ]
    }, {
      "value" : 0.2,
      "description" : "coord(1/5)"
    } ]
  }
}
```

and just in case where's what happens if i analyze the data i'm trying to store:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/instruments/_analyze?field=exact&pretty=true' -d 'ING  P JUN 2013 6.00'
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "ING  P JUN 2013 6.00",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 20,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  } ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All three documents get exactly the same score, as you can see from the explain output they all match on "AAPL". The term always appears once in the documents (tf=1) and it appears on 211 out of 37299 documents (idf=6.1701355). The field norm is much higher since you are using index time boosting (the boost part in your mapping, 10), anyway no big deal since the match is always on the same field. It's just that if you have a match on other fields exact would pretty much always win, which might make sense in your case.

But the problem is that `AAPL P JAN 2014 885,00` is not an exact match if I look at your documents. What I do see is that out of the 5 terms in your query only one matches, which is confirmed by the coord too in your explain output: coord(1/5)`.

The `keyword` analyzer seems to be applied, but as you see from the returned documents you are not sending the content of the `exact` field as a single value, but as an array of values. Each of its item won't be tokenized, since you are using the `keyword` analyzer, but still you have multiple tokens. I guess you have to check how you're indexing documents.

Comment: There is one with an exact match in there, it's just WAAAAAAAY down.

Comment: It's an exact match for you, not for elasticsearch/lucene if you look at the score.

Comment: What i don't get it: Why is it even matching ... i'm using the keyword analyzer which is supposed to analyze the whole string as a keyword ... so what i'm expacting is that when searches it turn the whole thing into a token, which it tries to match. But appearantly that's not what's happening. Any ideas how i can get my desired behavior? i only want a match if everything matches, down to the spaces. (Preferably case insensitive)

Comment: You are not tokenizing but adding different values to the same exact field: `["APPLE INC","US0378331005","AAPL","73773"]`. I think you have to fix the indexing part.

Comment: My use case is that my documents have a few (usually 4) values that uniquely identify them, if one of them matches exactly (case insensitive) I want that result on top (hence the boost 10) and if it doesn't match exactly i want it ignored.

Any suggestion as to how to get this sort of behavior ?

Comment: Make sure you apply the same text analysis when querying. It looks like the analyzer is applied at index bt not at query time. YOu can do it setting the searchAnalyzer in the mapping. otherwise even better if you set the field to not_analyzed and you use a term query.

Comment: I did set the analyzer to both query time and index time, but it didn't work. Still some other analyzer taking over during query time.
However using a termquery with a manual lowecase does seem to work. No idea why ES seems to be ignoreing the analyzer from my mapping, but the term query worked, so i'm all set, thx

Comment: @ConstantijnVisinescu field is an identifier, and as such should not be analyzed but instead used as unique identifier. Look at my suggested solution

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's technically the best thing but if you're just after a single specific answer from elastic search you could just use a filter with a script that looked for an exact match.

```
{
  from : 0,
  size : 1,
  "query" : { 
    "text_phrase" : { 
      "title" : "AAPL P JAN 2014 885,00"
    } 
  },
  "filter" : { 
    "script" : { 
      "script" : "_source.exact.contains(x)", 
      "params" : { 
        "x" : "AAPL P JAN 2014 885,00" 
      }  
    } 
  }
}
```

I've used this to obtain a single known entry from elastic search and it worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have found you answer, just wanted to give a bit more info for other with the same problem.

You use a `field` query which from the elasticsearch documentation:

> Field Query:
>
> A query that executes a query string against a specific field. It is a simplified version of query_string query (by setting the default_field to the field this query executed against).

I believe a `query_string` query is for text, i.e.: it does a lot to the query, making it fuzzy, etc...

What you want to use (and I think you found this out) is a `term` query which will not do anything to the search phrase, and so only give you exact matches.

NOTE: Analysis happens at 2 distinct times, index time and query time. Setting `"analyzer": "keyword"` seems to only affect search time queries "when searching using a query string" [form elasticsearch docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/core-types/). I must admit I don't know exactly what that means (I would guess `query_string` but it could also mean for searches like `http://../_search?q=exact:{query here}`)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your keyword analyzer seems to be ignored in the search query is because ES tokenizes this string twice - first it runs its DSL tokenizer and then it runs the tokenizer specified in the maping on the rezult. This is explained in more detail in this article http://paulsabou.com/blog/2012/03/25/advanced-exact-matching-with-elastic-search/

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT ANALYZE your id field.

Define your field as:

```
"exact":{
   "type":"string",
   "index":"not_analyzed"
 }
```

Have a look at [Finding Exact Values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html)